# Calculate the integral: $\int_0^{\pi/4} \tan^5(y/2)dy$

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate the integral: $\int_0^{\pi/4} \tan^5(y/2)dy$

my working out:

Take the u substitution for $y/2$ to get this integral:

$$2\int_0^{\pi/4} \tan^5(u)du$$

$$2\int_0^{\pi/4} \tan(u)(\sec^2(u)-1)(\sec^2(u)-1)du$$

$$\left(2\int_0^{\pi/4} \tan(u)\sec^4-4\int_0^{\pi/4}\tan(u)\sec^2(u)\space+2\int_0^{\pi/4}\tan(u)\right)du$$

The far right integral becomes: $2\ln(\sec(\pi/8))-2\ln(\sec(0))$
The middle integral becomes: $2\tan^2(\pi/8)-2\tan^2(0)$ via $v$ substitution for $v= \tan(u)$ and $dv = \sec^2(u)du$

How do I proceed with the first integral?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To proceed with the first integral you can substitute $v=\sec(u)$.

However, note that the limits of integration change after the substitution $u=\frac{y}{2}$ and also the integral you want should be

$$2\int \tan(u)\sec^{\color{red}{4}}(u)du=2\int \tan(u)\sec^2(u)(\tan^2(u)+1)du$$

and then substitute $v=\tan(u)$

Comment: Thanks for this! I have worked it out correctly now

Comment: You're very welcome :-)

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest is to use the identity $\tan'=1+\tan^2$, which allows us to proceed to the change of variable $v\gets\tan(u)$:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\pi/4}\tan^5(u)\,\mathrm du&=\int_0^{\tan{(\frac\pi4)}}v^5\,\frac{\mathrm dv}{1+v^2}\\[.4em]&=\int_0^1\frac{(v^3-v)(1+v^2)+v}{1+v^2}\,\mathrm dv\\[.4em]
&=\int_0^1v^3\,\mathrm dv-\int_0^1v\,\mathrm dv+\int_0^1\frac{v}{1+v^2}\,\mathrm dv\\[.4em]
&=\frac14-\frac12+\left[\frac12\,\log{(1+v^2)}\right]_0^1\\
&=-\frac14+\frac12\,\log 2
\end{align*}
(where we performed the Euclidean division of $v^5$ by $1+v^2$).

Comment: This looks very interesting! I'll have to study this approach some more

Comment: Note that the limit on the integral should be $\pi/8$ due to the substitution $u=y/2$.

Comment: @projectilemotion I copied the intermediate integral in OP's question but I think you're right. In this case the upper limit of the integral is $\tan(\frac\pi8)=\sqrt2-1$ instead of $1$. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

You have$$\int\tan(u)\sec^3(u)\,\mathrm du=\int\frac{\sin(u)}{\cos^4(u)}\,\mathrm du.$$Now, do $x=\cos(u)$ and $\mathrm dx=-\sin(u)\,\mathrm du$. You shall get that$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\tan(u)\sec^3(u)\,\mathrm du=\left[\frac{\sec^3(u)}3\right]_0^{\pi/4}=\frac{2\sqrt2-1}3.$$